# Union of $n$ open sets with nonzero reduced homology in dimensions $0$ through $n-2.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This question is inspired by Problem 2.2.33 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*.

Does there exist a space $X$ satisfying the following conditions for every $n \geq 2$? If not, for which $n$ is this possible?

- $X$ = $A_{1} \cup \cdots \cup A_{n}$, where each $A_{i}$ is open, and the intersection of any subcollection of the $A_{i}$'s is either empty or has trivial reduced homology groups in all dimensions.
- For each $0 \leq i \leq n-2,$ we have $H_{i}(X) \neq 0.$

In Hatcher's exercise we are asked to show that any $X$ satisfying the first condition must have $H_{i}(X) = 0$ for all $i \geq n-1$, and we are asked to give an example for each $n$ proving that this inequality is the best possible. It is not difficult to exhibit an example of an $X$ with $H_{n-2}(X) \neq 0$ for all $n$, but I wanted to see if we could do better and have the homology groups be nonzero for everything less than $n-1$.

My initial thoughts were to take $S^{0}, S^{1}, \ldots, S^{n-2}$ all connected to a common basepoint via straight lines, and then take an open $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of this space. The open sets would be the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of {the basepoint + the lines}, and the $\varepsilon$-neighborhoods of {$S_{i}$ minus the point where each line connects to $S^{i}$} for each $i$. Unfortunately, this "collection of lollipops" space doesn't work, because the intersection of the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of {the basepoint + the lines} and the $\varepsilon$-neighborhoods of the {$S^{i}$ minus point} can have noncontractible pairwise intersections with nonzero reduced homology.